# Preference based group generator

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for a polynomial time solution for the following problem:

$n$ number of students must be partitioned into $\frac{n - n\%m}{m}$ sets where $m$ is the ideal cardinality. Each pair of students has a value $r$ that denotes how much they want to be in a group with one another. The smaller the value is the more they want to be in a group each other and vice versa.

$n \ge m \cdot 2 \ge 4 $

This could be visualized in a simple, undirected, complete, weighted graph. The graph must be partitioned into $\frac{n - n\%m}{m}$ subgraphs with the same properties as the parent graph such that the sum of the sum of the weights of the subgraphs is minimal.

$n\%m$ amount of subgraphs will have one extra vertex in them $m+1$ the rest of the subgraphs will have $m$ amount of vertices in them.

If it's too complex you could start by considering how to solve this problem when $n\%m = 0$

$\%$ is the modulus operator.

I have included a link to an example graph to show what I mean. In the example $n =|V|= 4$ (there are 4 vertices, or 4 people: Person A, B, C and D). This is the smallest amount of people allowed. $m=2$ the ideal size of a group is in this case 2. Now that we have $n$ and $m$ we can calculate how many groups or subgraphs we need $\frac{4 - 4\%2}{2}=\frac{4 - 0}{2}=2$ the graph needs to be partitioned into 2 subgraphs of $m=2$ vertices. As you can see everyone has an $r$ value or weight to each other. We can quickly see that $w(A, C) = 1$ and $w(B, D) = 1$ are the best two groups that can be created in this case since $1 + 1 = 2$ is the lowest weight sum for 2 subgraphs of 2 vertices. I have encircled the two subgraphs consisting of vertex A and C and vertex B and D respectively on the image.

What I need is an algorithm that can solve this problem where $n$ and $m$ and the weights between them are variable. A much more complex situation where $n=31$ and $m=3$, for example, is probably more common.

In this case $n\%m=0$ but that is often not the case.

[Example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya3n6.png)

Comment: You may want to use other words like "sets" instead of "groups" and something else than generator. If you know some linear algebra you may also want to read up on spectral graph cuts.

Comment: Also it could be good to clarify that $\%$ is modulus operator ( at least I assume it is ). Not everyone on here knows programming language syntax for stuff.

Comment: Well, it's for a group generator and it was only to give a little context, but I get your point. I thought $\%$ was the standardized symbol for modulus in math, but I guess it doesn't hurt to add what I mean with it.

Comment: Yes maybe it is sometimes but I think a more common way to write $(bla\%blu) == ble$ is $ bla \equiv ble\,\, \text{mod}(blu)$

Comment: I could find something on spectral graph theory and graph cuts, but not spectral graph cuts specifically. Could you provide a link to it? Also, how is this related to my problem? Thanks.

Comment: The little graph theory I know is basically: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering It is about how to build matrices for the graphs and investigate their eigen-spectrum to find "clusterings" / cuts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65495/discussion-between-martin-and-mathreadler).

Comment: @mathreadler I updated the question to include an example.